# Http failure during parsing for url

Tags: json, angular

**login.ts**

```
onLogin() {
  let input = new FormData();
  input.append('email','ajith@gmail.com')
  input.append('password','12356789')
  this.http.post('http://worthyconsultants.in/training/api/v1/user/login',
  input,{responseType: 'json'}).subscribe(res=>{
    console.log(res)
     },
      err=>{
    console.log(err)
    }) 
   }
```

This is my Login function but the response is an error.says parsing error
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the response type is JSON? It looks like a php array

Comment: @AndreiDumitrescu-Tudor  Yes,Added the postman response

Comment: Can you also show the response headers in postman?

Comment: Response is not JSON. Try this header `{ 'Content-Type':'application/json'}`

Comment: @AndreiDumitrescu-Tudor Added

Comment: @Arcteezy for angular http client takes responseType as ‘json’ or ‘blob’.  can you remove the responseType Object and try again?

Comment: @Arcteezy Tudor  Still same error

Comment: Which Http module did you use? Http or HttpClient? And are you already sure that your API code works? The error can come from the API. If you have properly configured the API so that it returns JSON data?

Answer (score 0):

First you conform your post request send using POSTMAN tool if yes follow this link it help you or it may be backend side issue
[enter link description here][1]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HgKx36cpu60

Answer (score 0):

There was a print statement at the backend code,That's why it seems fine in the postman pretty view.